# Вычисление выражения после директивы EQU

Tags: c++

Есть такая задача:

Для повышения читабельности программ на языке ассемблера программисты пользуются именами. Для задания имени можно воспользоваться директивой EQU: имя EQU выражение, где имя – это определяемое программистом символическое имя, а выражение позволяет вычислить
значение имени. Пусть имя начинается с латинской буквы и содержит до 8 латинских букв или цифр. Выражение может быть целым числом, другим именем, суммой и/или разностью некоторого количества имен и/или целых положительных чисел. При этом к моменту обработки данной строки имена, входящие в выражение, могут еще не получить своих значений. Однако после обработки всех строк текста программы все имена получают свои значения. Гарантируется, что отсутствуют перекрестные ссылки среди выражений: если имя1 требует знания значения имя2, то имя2 не зависит от значения имя1. Требуется обработать последовательность директив EQU.

Пример входных данных:

```
Alpha EQU 5
Beta EQU Gamma–Delta+3
Gamma EQU Alpha+5
Delta EQU 17-Gamma+9
```

Пример выходных данных:

```
Alpha 5
Beta -3
Gamma 10
Delta 16
```

Я решил данную задачу, что мое решение проходит не все тесты. На одном из них выдает не правильный ответ, а на остальных превышение лимита по памяти. Так вот, я не знаю, в чем проблема. Предположу, что превышение лимита по памяти происходит в связи с чрезмерным стеком вызовов рекурсивной функций.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct var_name
{
    string name = "";
    int value = 0;
    bool full = false;
};

struct reference
{
    string var = "";
    vector<string> ref;
};

int findVar(const string& name, const vector<var_name>& names) {
    int res = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        if (names[i].name == name)
            return i;
    }
    return res;
}

int findRef(const string& name, const vector<reference>& references) {
    for (int i = 0; i < references.size(); i++) {
        if (references[i].var == name)
            return i;
    }
}

void calculateExpression(const vector<string>& operations, vector<reference>& references, vector<var_name>& names, const string& name) {
    var_name new_var;
    reference new_ref;
    new_var.full = true;
    new_ref.var = name;
    for (int i = 0; i < operations.size(); i++) {
        if (isdigit(operations[i][0])) { // число
            new_var.name = name;
            new_var.value += stoi(operations[i]);
        }
        else { // переменная
            int mult = 1;
            string oper = operations[i];
            if (operations[i][0] == '-') {
                mult = -1;
                oper = operations[i].substr(1, operations[i].size());
            }
            int indexVar = findVar(oper, names);
            if (indexVar == -1) {
                new_ref.ref.push_back(operations[i]);
                new_var.full = false;
                new_var.name = name;
            }
            else {
                new_var.name = name;
                new_var.value += mult * names[indexVar].value;
            }
        }
    }
    names.push_back(new_var);
    if (!new_ref.ref.empty())
        references.push_back(new_ref);
}

int calculateOther(const string& name, const vector<reference>& references, vector<var_name>& names) {
    int indexRef = findRef(name, references), indexCurVar = findVar(name, names);
    for (int i = 0; i < references[indexRef].ref.size(); i++) {
        int mult = 1;
        string oper = references[indexRef].ref[i];
        if (references[indexRef].ref[i][0] == '-') {
            mult = -1;
            oper = references[indexRef].ref[i].substr(1, references[indexRef].ref[i].size());
        }
        int indexVar = findVar(oper, names);
        if (names[indexVar].full) {
            names[indexCurVar].value += mult * names[indexVar].value;
        }
        else {
            int indexNewRef = findRef(references[indexRef].ref[i], references);
            names[indexCurVar].value += mult * calculateOther(references[indexNewRef].var, references, names);
        }
    }
    names[indexCurVar].full = true;
    return names[indexCurVar].value;
}

int main()
{
    string current = "", c_name = "";
    vector<string> cur_operations;
    vector<var_name> names;
    vector<reference> references;
    var_name c_var;
    int i = 0;

    while (getline(cin, current) && !current.empty()) {
        /* Обработка строки. Выделение названия переменной и операции */
        while (current[i] != ' ' && current[i] != '\t') // выделяем имя переменной
            c_name += current[i++];
        i = current.find("EQU") + 3;
        while (current[i] == ' ' || current[i] == '\t') i++;
        while (i < current.size()) {
            string tmp_operation = "";
            if (current[i] == '-' || current[i] == '+') {
                if (current[i] != '+')
                    tmp_operation += current[i];
                i++;
            }
            while (current[i] != '-' && current[i] != '+' && i < current.size()) tmp_operation += current[i++];
            cur_operations.push_back(tmp_operation);
        }

        calculateExpression(cur_operations, references, names, c_name); // генерируем значения и зависимости на первом проходе

        cur_operations.clear();
        c_name = "";
        i = 0;
    }

    // просчет переменных, зависимых от других
    bool f = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < references.size(); i++) {
        if (!names[findVar(references[i].var, names)].full)
            calculateOther(references[i].var, references, names);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
        cout << names[i].name << ' ' << names[i].value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```